# How to hide ArrayList in the JSP and get value to the next actionClass

Tags: jsp, struts2, arraylist, hidden

I'm stuck with in a place, where I want to generate a xls report, for which I need to pass the list to the JSP.

I'm getting data as null, I feel the hidden is not doing any good in setting the arrayList.

I'm using Struts 2.. Let me know if there is way to set the arrayList() as hidden in jsp, if so how do I do it.

Regards,
Senny

Comment: Can you print out the arrayList if it is not null? Please show the JSP (or a section of it) so we can better understand what you are trying to do, and possibly spot the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Struts only provides type conversions for the most common object types/primitives (see http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/type-conversion.html). If your ArrayList contains complex objects that aren't supported by the default struts2 converters, then this may be why you are not getting the data.